# LINQ: Why does a union of a union throw error message "IQueryable<...> does not contain a definition for 'Union'"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

The question is about **nesting unions in LINQ**: I want to combine data from tables in 3 different databases and show them in one result table.

---

To make it clear what I want to achieve, I am showing how that would be done in SQL (I am using the Northwind, Nutshell and Pubs databases so it is easier for you to try it out by yourself):

```
SELECT 'Territories' as [Table], TerritoryDescription as Item, RegionID as ID 
  FROM Northwind.dbo.Territories
UNION
SELECT 'MedicalArticles' as [Table], Topic as Item, ID as ID  
  FROM Nutshell.dbo.MedicalArticles
UNION
SELECT 'Authors' as [Table], City as Item, Zip as ID 
  FROM pubs.dbo.Authors
```

The underlying table structure is:
[image: table structure]
This query works fine without errors and returns a table with 3 columns (Table, Item and ID), combining the data from the 3 tables Territories, MedicalArticles and Authors:

[image: Result]

And if you add a `top 3` to each of the 3 select statements, you'll get:

[image: ResultTop3]

---

Now I've tried the same in **LINQ** by writing code like:

```
void Main()
{
    // In LinqPad:
    // Drag + Drop databases from Schema explorer to code window with pressed Ctrl key
    var dc = this; // database context: Northwind + Nutshell + pubs

    // first database Northwind is default
    var q1 = (from s in dc.Territories select new { Table = "Territories", 
                Item = s.TerritoryDescription, ID = s.RegionID }).Distinct().Take(5); 

    // second database .Nutshell needs to be referenced
    var q2 = (from s in dc.Nutshell.MedicalArticles select new { Table="MedicalArticles", 
                Item = s.Topic, ID=s.ID }).Distinct().Take(5); 

    // third database .Pubs needs to be referenced
    var q3 = (from s in dc.Pubs.Authors select new { Table = "Authors", 
                Item = s.City, ID = s.Zip }).Distinct().Take(5); 

    // union q1 with q2 works
    var u1 = q1.Union(q2.Select(s => s)); u1.Dump();

    // but union u1 with q3 does not work
    //var u2 = u1.Union(q3.Select(s => s)); u2.Dump();      
}
```

The first union (q1 with q2) works fine - but I can't apply the 3rd query q3 to the result (i.e. `u1.Union(q3.Select(s => s))` doesn't work).

The error message I am getting when I uncomment the line querying u2 isn't very helpful:

> `CS1929 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, int ID>>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, string ID>>(ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, string ID>>, IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, string ID>>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, string ID>>'`

**How can the error be fixed?**

---

**Note:** The examples above can be tried out in LinqPad. Simply place the code in a window and then add the 3 databases Northwind, NutShell and Pubs by holding the Ctrl key and then drag+drop the database to the query window.

Comment: Most likely the type of  the `ID`  property in the anonymous type projections is different. Check the type of `RegionID` and `Zip`.

Comment: According to documentation, you qpply Union on an IQueryable, not an IEnumerable. This is the error you have here. Maybe try to replace your code with : var u2 = u1.AsQueryable().Union(q3.Select(s => s));

Comment: @Florian There are overloads for both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`. It's not specific to `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Servy : yes indeed ! My comment shouldn't be considered. It seems to be, as first comment highlighted, an anonymous projection fail.

Comment: Is that error message the full error message?. I would have expected it to include the types, ie something like `CS1929 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Table, string Item, int ID>>' does not contain ...`  etc.

Comment: @sgmoore - Right, the message was truncated due to a formatting issue. Now you can see the complete error.

Comment: The error message shows that Ivan was correct and Zip is a string whereas RegionID is an int. A workaround would be to change `ID = s.RegionID` to `ID = s.RegionID.ToString()` and `ID=s.ID` to `ID=s.ID.ToString()`

Comment: @sgmoore - You are right, I've just checked it. This is the correct answer. If you add it as answer, I'll accept it. Many thanks to all who contributed! :-)

Comment: Plus 1,Not sure why this receive downvotes seems like a well written valid question.

Comment: @johnny5 - thank you, much appreciated!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to all who contributed above in the comments!
I created this answer from the comments from [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) and [sgmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125759/sgmoore):

*"Most likely the type of the `ID` property in the anonymous type projections is different. Check the type of `RegionID` and `Zip`."* - Ivan

*"The error message shows that `Zip` is a string whereas `RegionID` is an int. A workaround would be to change `ID = s.RegionID` to **`ID = s.RegionID.ToString()`** and `ID=s.ID` to **`ID=s.ID.ToString()`**."* - sgmoore

That is definitely the solution. As it seems, type checking in C# is stricter than in SQL (recap, in SQL the union worked without any additional typecasting).

But the error message is definitely misleading (*"IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Union'"*), which is why the question was asked. A more meaningful error message would be helpful here.

Comment: The full error message was quite to the point. `'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition of 'Union'` is completely true, and that would be the first thing the compiler looked for and failed to find. It would then have looked for an extension method and failed to find one that was applicable because of the type mismatch. The closest find wasn't great, but it's a fair stab at trying to report on what was attempted and failed.

Comment: @JonHanna - But what has that to do with a "Receiver of type ParallelQuery"? To be honest, I don't understand the complete error message.

Comment: Because you'd asked the compiler to find a matching `.Union()` where there was none and the one that expects a `ParallelQuery` was the one (or a joint first) that seemed closest. The problem with any such error message is when you've been asked to do the impossible making a guess at what was wanted is never going to be 100% perfect, by the very nature of being asked to do the impossible.

Comment: @JonHanna - Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. Btw. I never thought that the compiler was going to guess :-D

Comment: It pretty much did guess, as best it could. Compiling correct code is sometimes hard, producing good error messages for incorrect code is always hard :)

Comment: @JonHanna - That's so true - as [Augustus De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) said 1866 (many years before the computer was invented): What can go wrong will go wrong, right? ;-)